# GET http://localhost:8100/json.php 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I'm getting the following error: GET http://localhost:8100/json.php 404 (Not Found). After researching the problem it seems to be a CORS problem, but I'm still struggling to fix the problem

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:8100/db/json.php").subscribe( data => {
  this.productList = JSON.parse(data["_body"]);
}, err =>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

json.php is under the directory src/app/db/json.php (working with Ionic/Angular) and I have header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); at the top.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what makes you think it's a `CORS` issue, for me it looks like the file isn't hosted in a way you think it is

Comment: Are you sure it is not meant have `app` in the url? Something like `http://localhost:8100/app/db/json.php`?

Comment: CORS seemed to be causing this problem for others so I assumed it was the same in this case. How would you suggest fixing this?

Comment: Didn't fix it I'm afraid

Comment: Are you getting any CORS errors/warnings on the browser console?
Also can you try console.log(data) in your subscribe

Comment: A 404 is not a CORS error. If it was a CORS error, then you should see error message in the console, explicitly saying that.

Comment: _“json.php is under the directory src/app/db/json.php”_ - and what directory does `http://localhost:8100/` point to?

Comment: CORS errors are thrown when I remove the db/ from http://localhost:8100/db/json.php.

Comment: It's never actually getting to creating the data I believe, nothing's being printed in the console.log

Comment: You should understand the status codes of the xhr/api request you are making 400 is client making some issue and 500 is server issue. This will clear most of your ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line at starting of your PHP file and keep your php script on php supported server e.g. wamp

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: did you check http://localhost:8100/app/db/json.php is accessible from your browser...?

Answer (score 0):

1. This may be your folder location issue.
2. Please first make sure that the url you are providing in get request is correct 
   or not.
3. The folder structure should be like this:-
    src->app->db->your php file
4. If Your db folder is under the app folder then only you call this file like:-
    http://localhost:8100/db/json.php
5. Make sure you are using the same way